# React js MapBox Routes

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, action

I have a problem, I am already developing an application with react js using mapbox, my problem is what I want to draw routes in the map from a given position. How do I do it?

Comment: Pleas provide your code.

Comment: https://github.com/StephaneCash/LocG_F/blob/main/src/view/FindGarage.js

Answer (score 0):

Here you have few great source how to do it:

1. Add a line to a map using a GeoJSON [source](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/)
2. Animate a point along a [route](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-route/)
3. Support for drawing and editing features on mapbox-gl.js [maps.](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw)

---

Good Luck ;-)